# IIS how to determine ApplicationPoolIdentity account?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, account, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

`Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard ( Microsoft Windows Server Version 6.1 Build 7601: Service Pack 1 )`

`IIS 7.5.7600.16385`

In `IIS Manager` for a `Site` assigned an `ApplicationPool` with `Identity` = `ApplicationPoolIdentity` ( the default setting ) , how to determine the Windows account the site uses for directory operations ?

In previous versions of `IIS`, `Application Pools` run under the `Network Service` account.

What is default account for `ApplicationPoolIdentity` ?

`IIS Manager` > `Server Instance` > `Application Pools` > `Application Pool` > right-click `Set Application Pool Defaults...` --OR-- `Advanced Settings`

both invoke the same dialog which contains an `Identity` field with `...` button that allows setting the Identity -- no where does it specify what account is associated with `ApplicationPoolIdentity` or allow that value to be set

Answer (score 55):

The ApplicationPoolIdentity under IIS 7+ is a local machine account named the same name as the application pool itself and resides under a special domain called IIS AppPool. For example given the application pool name MyAppPool your application pool identity user would be IIS AppPool\MyAppPool.

You can learn more about how this works from this Microsoft link...
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Is this true on IIS 10? I am not seeing a user with the app pool name when trying to set permissions on the web root.

Comment: The user is hidden when you search while setting permissions for example. If you type in IIS AppPool\MyAppPool and click "Check Name" it will resolve to a valid local user.

Comment: in IIS 10 user would be IIS AppPool\<apppool name>

Comment: The step that I missed was, as mentioned in the linked article, setting the location to the machine in the search

Answer (score 7):

For IIS 10 user would be:

```
IIS AppPool\<apppool name>
```